# CRM 2011 javascript onchange event not working for system field in another organisation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have some javascript code attached to the accounts entity. This code sets the requirement level of the primary contact attribute based on the value of a custom option set field showing various account types. This was developed on one server, where it worked, and so the solution was imported into another organisation where it now doesnt work.

It seems to be only on this field as i have changed the code to look at another field and that works fine. The error it gives is that the "Object doesn't support this property or method". Also what is strange is that the field doesn't appear in the list under the entity within the solution despite it being a system field.

The code i'm using is:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("primarycontactid").setRequiredLevel("required");
```

Can anyone help me figure out what it's doing?

Thanks

EDIT: Found that the code is actually making the field required despite the error, but it's not displaying the * next to it. Also if I make the field required in it's settings then it does the same thing

Comment: I believe so yes, they were both set up at the same time

Comment: But you could install a rollup on one post installation and not on the other. The reason I ask to check for differences between your two environments.

Comment: I've just had a check and you are correct, one is saying 5.0.9690.2243 and the other is 5.0.9688.1533

Comment: I've just updated them so they are now on the same version and it has fixed the issue, thank you very much for your help!